# Link between Excel and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I've made a trivial program so that I can put data on my database, but as of today, I've had some problems when trying to export data.
First, the error message I got was: `"no value given for one or more required parameters."` And then (I didn't change anything), I got a new error message: `"Attempted to read or write protected memory, this is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."`
How can I solve this problem, And do you think it's a good program to do that?
Is there a better way to write and read on my database through Excel?

```
 Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
   Dim CnxExcel As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & TextBox1.Text & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";")
   Dim CnxSql As New SqlConnection("Data Source=TODL300083400\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Charges;Integrated Security=True")
   Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
   Dim ds As New DataSet

   Dim cmdGammes As New OleDbCommand("select [CodeGamme], [StatutGamme] from [Gammes$]", CnxExcel)

   da.SelectCommand = cmdGammes
   da.Fill(ds, "Gammes")

   Dim InterGammes As New SqlBulkCopy(CnxSql)

   CnxSql.Open()

   InterGammes.DestinationTableName = "TempGammes"
   InterGammes.WriteToServer(ds.Tables("Gammes"))
 End Sub
```

Comment: Is your excel file open? You can have problems connecting to it when it is open. Make sure it is closed and that no process use it.

Comment: Actually, It doesn't work even if my excel file is closed. I've find out something interesting: when I specify the colomuns' names which contain the data I want to export to my table, it doesn't work. However when I copy only those columns in a new sheet and change my selection (select * ) it works. 
It's strange !

Comment: try to remove the [ ] surronding the comumn names. They are not required.

Comment: I removed them but it doesn't work ! :( 
If there is a better way to ensure the link between my Excel file and my database please don't hesitate to share it with me.

Comment: I tried a lot of things. The problem is still the same: "no value given for one or more required parameters." 
Please help me !

Comment: It is hard to say, there may be a problem with your file, for some reason the query seems to not be able to find the columns. Maybe you should try just querying one column at the time to see if that works, maybe transfering the data on another file, maybe selecting the right tab on your from...